# Как отключить IspManager?

Tags: ispmanager

Привет.

Как отключить ISPmanager Lite 5 на ОС Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте "убить" процесс

```
sudo killall ispmgr
```

или

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo killall ihttpd
```

запуск

```
/usr/local/ispmgr/sbin/ihttpd IP_адрес_сервера порт_сервера
```

Comment: А при перезапуски сервера, они снова не запустятся?

Comment: `update-rc.d -f apache2 remove`

Comment: Как вариант удалить ISPmanager в текущей системе и запускать через Docker контейнер когда вам это необходимо https://hub.docker.com/r/mirhosting/ispmanager-lite-debian-8/